# How do I study the effect of body bias on threshold voltage with a plot of Ids vs Vgs for different values of Vbs using LTSpice tool?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

How can I get the plot for different values of VBS in a single plot so as to clearly show the threshold voltage variation?

Comment: How would you study the threshold voltage vs drain current for a regular MOSFET that doesn't have a bulk pin? Can you do this?

Comment: ' http://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm: 
... 
Monolithic MOSFET: Syntax: Mxxx Nd Ng Ns Nb <model> [m=<value>] [L=<len>] 
... 
Monolithic MOSFETS are four terminal devices. Nd, Ng, NS, and Nb are the drain, gate, source, and bulk; i.e., substrate; nodes. ... '. So, draw a circuit and run sweep simulations

Comment: @Andyaka "Obviously" you need a 4-pin MOSFET so that rules out (as far as I know) all off-the-shelf MOSFETs since these have their bulk (or body, whatever you call it) and source **shorted**. But in a **simulator** we can have 4-terminal MOSFETs. Maybe you're hinting at the fact that LTSPice does not have any models like that! You could make your own though if you have a Spice model for example.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie no, I'm trying to establish if the OP knows how to do basic stuff on a regular MOSFET first before trying something before he understands the basics. It was his use of the term "LTSpice tool" in his title that made me suspect he'd never used LTSpice previously. Most folk would just say "LTSpice".

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a 4-terminal MOSFET model / symbol (not sure if LTSpice comes with that, if not you could make one if you have a suitable MOSFET model)
2. I would use this schematic testbench:

[image]

(since the schematic drawing tool doesn't include a 4-terminal MOSFET, I edited the schematic by hand, I removed the short between bulk-source, so now it is a picture)

You can use the left or the right schematic, it depends on personal preference.

The MOSFET is configured as a "MOS-diode" and biased at a small current (start with 1 uA for example).  Then Vgs will be roughly equal to the threshold voltage, so you can just plot Vgs.

A more accurate method would be to plot the actual threshold voltage value that is used inside the MOSFET model. For that you might need to perform many DC operating point simulations and combine the results in one plot (I am unsure of LTSpice can do that, I use a more advanced simulator: Cadence Spectre).

Left circuit:

Do note that Vbody < 0 V so you need to give Vbody a **negative** value!

(Bonus question: what "goes wrong" when Vbody > 0 V ?)

Right circuit:

Vsource can be positive, when Vsource = 1 V then Vbs = -1 V.

Start with a DC simulation where you sweep Vbody or Vsource and plot the resulting Vgs.

Comment: LTspice does have a built-in symbol, `nmos4`, or `pmos4`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now.

As the requirement is for a single plot of Ids Vs Vgs showing the cases for each value of Vbs, then Vbs could be specified as variable {Vbs} for the voltage source value and then ".step parameter  Vbs [initial val] [final] [step]" added in LTSpice design using op.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. I think you're using 'Answer' on this site like 'Reply' is used on other discussion sites. This is new information and should be edited into your question. Otherwise, readers have to piece all of this together to understand it. As this is not an answer, it will most likely be deleted but you can delete it yourself if you like, before any downvotes reduce your Reputation. Thanks.

Comment: This is a legitimate answer, I see no problem with it (except for the thanks part.)